# Воспроизводится песня в html5 при постороннем звуке

Tags: html5

Приложение создано с помощью phonegap.
На странице одной поставил аудио. Нажимаю на паузу, и если даже сверну приложение, и н-р кто-нибудь напишет мне сообщение и выйдет звук уведомления то аудио в приложении начинает продолжать играть. При чем клавиша показывает, что аудио еще стоит на паузе. 
Как избавиться от этого бага?

Проверил, при любом звуковом оповещении аудио продолжает петь. Т.е. один звук запускает другой. Если переставить телефон в режим беззвучный, то все норм.

```
  <audio preload="none" controls ontimeupdate="if (this.duration == this.currentTime) {this.currentTime  = 0; this.pause()} " id = "audio'+i+'" src="file:///sdcard/Download/Tur/1.mp3"></audio>

<button id = "vklvikl" onclick = "if (!audio'+[i]+') {document.getElementById(\'audio'+i+'\').play(); audio'+[i]+'= true;} else {document.getElementById(\'audio'+i+'\').pause(); audio'+[i]+'= false;}"> play/pause</button>
```

Comment: видимо вы через jquery делаете что-то типа $('.audio').play() на все события, что на сообщения, что на музыку. а вообще, чтобы не напрягать телепатов, не могли бы вы куски кода выдать ? а-то сейчас даже не понятно в одном ли приложении звук играется.

Comment: Сообщения с другого приложения.

Comment: т.е. любое звуковое оповещение из любого приложения в вашей OS запускает play в любой html5 странице в браузере ? опишите платформу пожалуйста. OS/браузер/версии. это бредово если честно.

Comment: Android 4.0.4.
Программа запускается в виде приложения. Какой он там браузер использует я не знаю. Причем, если включить атрибут controls, то видно, что ползунок перемещается, на клавиша плей не активна.

Comment: проигрывание началось, просто кнопка плей не обновила статус. Что Вы хотите от PhoneGap... А вот почему оно запустилось - нужно logcat смотреть, может там и всплывет что-то.

Comment: попробуйте поспрашивать на форумах phonegap, опишите подробно им проблему, возможно это баг в андроиде. вообще, насколько я понял html5 audio не шибко хорошо работает в андроиде. браузер webview.

Comment: Похоже это баг прошивки.Тестил на другом телефоне, все норм.